# I did not understand why q96 used here in uniswapV3 development book

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, python, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

This code is from Uniswap v3 development book:

```py
sqrtp_low = price_to_sqrtp(4545)
sqrtp_cur = price_to_sqrtp(5000)
sqrtp_upp = price_to_sqrtp(5500)

def liquidity0(amount, pa, pb):
    if pa > pb:
        pa, pb = pb, pa
    return (amount * (pa * pb) / q96) / (pb - pa)       # HERE

def liquidity1(amount, pa, pb):
    if pa > pb:
        pa, pb = pb, pa
    return amount * q96 / (pb - pa)          # HERE

eth = 10**18
amount_eth = 1 * eth
amount_usdc = 5000 * eth

liq0 = liquidity0(amount_eth, sqrtp_cur, sqrtp_upp)
liq1 = liquidity1(amount_usdc, sqrtp_cur, sqrtp_low)
liq = int(min(liq0, liq1))
```

As we already calculated the sqrt of current,lower and upper price why did we divided and multiplied by `q96` again?

Answer (score 1):

`q96` is a **fixed-point number** used for **precise calculations**
I'm not really familiar with Vyper but from my understanding this formula multiplies token amounts and prices, then divides by `q96` and price difference `(pb - pa)`

> A fixed-point number is a way of representing decimal numbers in
> binary format. It is called "fixed" because it has a fixed number of
> digits to the right of the decimal point. The number of digits to the
> right of the decimal point is predetermined and does not change, hence
> the term "fixed".

I suggest you to read this https://blog.finxter.com/data-types-in-solidity-smart-contract-part-20-fixed-point-numbers-address-and-address-type-members/

Answer (score 0):

It is the way that fixed point multiplication and division work.

Let's use M = 1000 as the base, so 1 is represented as 1000, 0.5 is represented as 500, etc. Let's suppose we have the numbers: `X = x*M`, and `Y = y*M`.

Now `X*Y = x*M * y*M = x*y * M*M`, we have an extra M so we have to 'scale down' the result `X*Y/M = x*y * M`.

Similarly for the division `X/Y = (x*M)x / (y*M) = x/y` and we are missing the M. We have to 'scale up' the result `X/Y * M = x/y * M`.

For example: `X = 1200` and `Y = 400`, then `X*Y / 1000 = 1200*400/1000 = 480`. Which is the representation of `1.2 * 0.4 = 0.48`.

Similarly `X = 1200`, `Y = 400`, then `X/Y * 1000 = 1200 / 400 * 1000 = 3000`. Which is the representation of `1.2 / 0.4 = 3`.